# What should I do if believe a moderator is biased?

Tags: discussion, moderation

What is the best way to handle a situation where I believe a moderator is biased?

If a moderator is the problem, who moderates the moderator?

Comment: I edited this to remove the commentary, which is unnecessary and inflammatory.

Comment: @enderland - there is nothing in that question that was "unnecessary and inflammatory". I called attention to a **specific problem** in order to focus on the issue, and since said moderator has shown bias, it was necessary to warn about recusal, because those who are biased tend to meddle. If my rejected edit changed the meaning of the question "What are tools/resources I can use to check a company for ** and ** during a job search?" as alleged, your edit has changed the meaning of my question **far more**. Your edit is heavy handed and invasive.

Comment: I recall reading somewhere that you can request that a specific moderator not handle your flags... however in your specific cause I don't think the moderator is biased against you. It seems like your points of view are merely different from the moderator, and not shared by the OP or most members of the community, so the preference is to let the OP leave their post the way it is.

Comment: @Vector my edit changed the question to be one which is on topic for a meta site. If you insist on having it be a rant against a current moderator it is very likely the post will be deleted by the community

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If there is actually a moderator that is as biased as you claim, there should be individual moderator actions that are problematic. You can bring those actions to meta and see if the community agrees with you that they were incorrect.

There is one extremely important aspect when bringing the issue up here on meta, and that is to make it about the individual decisions, not about the moderator as a person. Your meta post shouldn't even mention the name of the moderator acting, just the post and the facts. This kind of issue is handled far, far better if everyone stays close to the facts and avoids making the issue personal.

A reasonable moderator will change their behaviour if they are convinced that some of their past actions were incorrect. Often such disagreements simply indicate an area where the commmunity hasn't come to a consensus on the rules, and a meta discussion can solve this by coming up with better rules.

If a moderator is continuing to misuse their position in your view, use the "contact us" link in the footer. The complaints about moderators will be handled by the SE commmunity team. They moderate the moderators, and can talk to them or in the worst case also dismiss them.

Comment: _Your meta post shouldn't even mention the name of the moderator acting, just the post and the facts_ : This was unnecessary. It is clear from my question that I was quite careful NOT to mention any names. Obviously I am aware of this issue.

Comment: @Vector - remember, this answer is not just for you, but for the benefit of others who might be having similar problems. While you may already have known to avoid naming names, others may benefit from that suggestion.

Comment: Dont bring them to meta of the site though, that will get you suspended...  Do it on Meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Chad words of wisdom that are still true 2 years later.